# Use drivers from windows to linux

Tags: linux, windows, networking, wine, wifi-driver

I have this wifi card: WG311v3 - G54 Wireless PCI Adapter;

that only work in Windows with specific driver.
How can i use it too with GNU/Linux ?

I read about the wine program but  [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=957601) they said that we can't install drivers in wine.

Is there an other solution ?

Comment: Does the wifi card "just work" in Linux now? Tried searching for the exact card (or however it's identified in Linux) plus "linux"?

Comment: What make and model wifi card? I note that WIFI cards are relatively cheap, and it may pay - even in a notebook - to simply replace the card.

Comment: Do an `lspci -n` under Linux. This will give you the vendor and product id which you can use (in the form `0123:4567`) to find out if the card is supported under Linux.

Comment: Yep, was easy to find instructions for using ndiswrapper with this card, though finding the download for the driver binaries was a *little* tricky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tool for getting Windows network drivers to work in Linux is called NdisWrapper ([wiki](http://ndiswrapper.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), [downloads](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ndiswrapper/)). NDIS (Network Device Interface Specification) is the Windows network driver API; NdisWrapper is a Linux kernel module that basically presents a fake Windows kernel to a Windows network driver and translates between that and normal the Linux network driver interface.

NdisWrapper isn't perfect - it doesn't support all drivers and it may crash your Linux system - and free software advocates don't like it because it's basically loading proprietary code (the Windows driver) into a F/LOSS OS kernel. With that said, though, it often can be made to work. You may have better luck using drivers targeted at older Windows versions, since the NDIS spec changes somewhat over time; if you can't find an XP driver for the card, look for a Vista/Win7 one, then Win8/8.1 if you can't find that.

It's a little more complicated to install and configure than is typical for either native Linux drivers or drivers on Windows, but if you want to run Linux on not-fully-compatible hardware it may just let you do that thing.

### Edit

Since you added the version, I did a search for "WG311v3 Linux", which led me to quite a few links. Consensus seemed to be that yeah, no native Linux support but it works fine in ndiswrapper. Many pages contained dead links for the old (XP) driver download, but by following a link from the very first result I found https://sites.google.com/site/subtlegems/netgear-wg311v3-ndis-driver-for-linux-amd64. That page not only has a live link, it contains both 32-bit and 64-bit drivers as actual driver binaries (`.sys` files) for XP. These binaries are confirmed compatible with ndiswrapper, at least on old versions (and should still work fine), and you can also find links to install directories. So, there you go!

Comment: Thanks,but to install my driver you need to execute a .exe program and i don't have the [install cd.](http://ndiswrapper.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Netgear_WG311v3)

Comment: @user-707 The `.exe` contains the `.sys` file that is the actual driver. Try using a file unpacker (7-Zip on windows, perhaps `ark` or similar on Linux) and you should be able to extract the actual driver binary. Alternatively, just do a search for "<card name> ndiswrapper" and see if there are any instructions. Since you didn't specify the actual card for us here, we can't offer very specific instructions...

Comment: My mistake, its a [setup file](http://www.netgear.com/support/product/WG311v3.aspx#download) which must be executed also please see my edit.

Comment: one more thing: i have used the ndis gui tool instead of the cli utility and it just ask for the **.INF** file.

Comment: there's issues with the driver posted in the google link,sometimes the network disconnect itself,but not in windows,maybe it's because bugs has been fixed since the driver in windows is the newest.Also what do you meant by "extract the actual driver binary",even if we do this we can't use it on linux to upgrade the driver. Cordially.

Comment: @user-707 Sorry to hear about the problems. You might be able to get a newer driver to work; I haven't tried. "The actual driver binary" is the `.sys` file - an actual PE-format binary file containing executable code - that the kernel loads into its driver stack. That file is the one Ndiswrapper needs. The old (XP) driver installer has the `.sys` files right there in the unpacked archive, but the newer ones bundle them into the setup program. That setup program has to at some point cough up such a binary, though; Windows needs one to load. Find it and Ndiswrapper can probably use it too.

Comment: found it and yes ndiswrapper use it too,thanks again.